# Do C# objects know the type of the more specific class?

Tags: c#, object, types

Suppose you create a generic Object variable and assign it to a specific instance. If you do GetType(), will it get type Object or the type of the original class?

Comment: Have you tried the 10 or so lines of code to try this?

Comment: Yep -- I did this as a "had a question and wanted to share the answer" post :)

Comment: ...posted same time as your trial answer!

Comment: Yeah, I was debating whether to include the "answer" in the question but thought it'd look weird.

Comment: You posted a question just so you could answer your own question?  This isn't a blog, it is a Q&A site.  Are you fishing for cred?

Comment: Nope -- just wanted to answer a question that took me a second to think about.

From the FAQ: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: Ok, if it is in the FAQ, I will take back my downmod... not very happy about it, though. :)

Comment: Hey, the SO FAQs specifically encourage people to answer their own questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq#119658
Can I Answer My Own Question? What If It's Not Really a Question? Yes! It's even encouraged.

Comment: No worries :). Yeah, I remember hearing that SO could be used as a "snippets/gotcha" repository. I still struggle with the right way to record these though -- maybe a special tag?

Comment: I am cool with answering your own question.  I do wonder about "Hey, I know an answer, I will ask a question just so I can answer it".  Oh well, it is in the FAQ, so I took back my down-mod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can also do:

```
object c = new FooBar();
if(c is FooBar)
     Console.WriteLine("FOOBAR!!!");
```

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: GetType() will return the Type of the specific object.** I made a quick app to test this:

```
        Foo f = new Foo();
        Type t = f.GetType();

        Object o = (object)f;
        Type t2 = o.GetType();

        bool areSame = t.Equals(t2);
```

And yep, they are the same.

Comment: use: 

if(o is Foo)
 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Calling GetType() will call the ACTUAL type.  If you want to know the base type, you can call GetType().BaseType